# Extract nested array from JSON response PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have been having an issue for days where I can't extract data from a JSON response. Please see below:

```
{ 
"ok": [ 
    "{'name': 'will', 'age': '10', 'group': 'green 1', 'birth-month: 'Jan', 'durationInSeconds': 485.334605}",
    "{'name': 'jack', 'age': '15', 'group': 'green 2', 'birth-month: 'Dec', 'durationInSeconds': 485.334605}",
    "{'name': 'emma', 'age': '12', 'group': 'red 1', 'birth-month: 'Oct', 'durationInSeconds': 485.334605}"
]
}
```

I need to loop through each array and ideally create an output like:
Name:will
Age:10
Group: green 1
etc.... for each array, but no matter what I try, I can't achieve this

Comment: Can you show what code you have tried and we can perhaps help fix your problems from there.

Comment: `foreach ($variable['ok'] as $person)`

Comment: Then print `$person['name']`, `$person['age']`, etc.